# WebStorm 2020.3 - how to enable React props intellisense?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I am working on React project and WebStorm is my IDE but I have noticed than whenever I want to write some props for my components I am not getting properly intellisense. I am using Create-`React-App` and `React-CSS-Modules` as styling library.

[image]

Checkbox component:

```
const CheckboxWrapperInner = ({
  isSelected,
  customStyleName = 'checkbox',
  hex6Color = '#221ecc',
  additionalSelectedStyles = {
    borderColor: hex6Color || '#221ecc',
  },
  additionalUnselectedStyles = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  label,
  onClick = () => {},
}) 

// ... some code

const CheckboxInner = ({...rest}) => {
  return <CheckboxWrapper customStyleName="checkbox" {...rest}></CheckboxWrapper>;
};

const CheckboxWrapper = CSSModules(CheckboxWrapperInner, style, {
  allowMultiple: true,
  handleNotFoundStyleName: 'ignore',
});
export const Checkbox = CSSModules(CheckboxInner, style, {allowMultiple: true});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

props completion doesn't work for components with HOC (like `export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent)`, etc.). And each HOC requires adding a special support.
Related tickets: [WEB-38369](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38369), [WEB-47862](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-47862)